# How to show string on JLabel such that each alphabet should be displayed after certain period of time

Tags: java

I want to print a string on `JLabel` but each alphabet should be added after certain period of time. I had used threads in my program.

When I am running my program the `JLabel` is replacing the last alphabet and adding the new one.What should i do that the `JLabel` will append each alphabet of my string.

Here is my program:

```
public class Thread_in_Swing extends JFrame implements Runnable {
    String s="HELLO PRASHANT";
    JLabel lb=new JLabel();

    Thread_in_Swing() { 
        lb.setBounds(10,50,200,40);

        add(lb);

        setLayout(null);
        setTitle(s);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Thread_in_Swing t1=new Thread_in_Swing();
         t1.run();     
    }  

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String a;
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++) {
            a=Character.toString(s.charAt(i));
            lb.setText(a);
            try {   
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    }  
}
```

My program is executing properly and after 1 sec it is printing alphabets in `String s` by replacing the last one but I want each alphabet should be append the previous.

Comment: `lb.setText(lb.getText() + a)`

Answer (score 0):

When you get new character you have to append it to your previously generated string. So you can simply do lb.setText(lb.getText()+a)